# React Native Image / Panresponder

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I'm trying to get the position of a touch relative to the element(Image), the component looks like this:

```
<Image
   resizeMode={'contain'}
   {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
   style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        width: null,
        height: null,
    }}
    source={{ uri }}
/>
```

The image is taking the full width like it should and the height is dynamic(so that it's not stretching the picture). However when im logging this:

```
onPanResponderGrant: (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.nativeEvent.locationX)
    console.log(evt.nativeEvent.locationY)
},
```

and triggering a touch event in the upper left corner (close to 0,0) im not getting values like (5, 5) for example, im getting 5 for the X value and like 200 for the Y value. I should add that im positioning the image in the middle of the screen with justifyContent: 'center'.

My guess is that the image takes all the space it can get and just showing the picture without stretching it (paddingVertical).

Does anyone know how I can make the picture to only take the height that it actually needs without knowing the size of the picture ?

Comment: Can you show a picture of your screen?  And where are you applying the pan handlers?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already solved the issue by calculating the aspect ratio and multiplying it with the screenWidth so I can get a height of the picture. The panresponder had no influence on this.